# click event on anchor tag after insertAfter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added html on run time using `.insertAfter()` method of jQuery:

```
var options = '<div class="selectyoursize_block" id="selectyoursize_block_left" style="display:none;"><ul><li><a href="#">S</a></li><li><a href="#">M</a></li><li><a href="#">L</a></li><li><a href="#">XL</a></li><li><a href="#">XXL</a></li></ul></div>';
$(options).insertAfter(selector.eq(4)).slideDown();

$("#selectyoursize_block_left a").on("click", function(e){});
```

But nothing is working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean its not working? What do you want it to do? It works fine, Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhyjte6j/). I just used another selector tho. Check your console for errors. Make sure your have jQuery library and also check your "selector" make sure its defined properly.

Comment: hi amin thanks for the reply. yes i have properly checked including library and selector also.Is this the thing that the html not included while the DOM is being ready?

Comment: what are you trying to achive ?

Comment: Oh i think whats your problem, the answer you got should help you also read [This](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) too

Comment: You're not re-using ids or anthing like that are you? Is the HTML structure after the insertAfter what you expect?

Comment: actually i want to set custom attribute say 'data' with the value to every anchor tag.By clicking on those links want to get that value.

Answer (score 0):

Move the selector to the 2nd parameter selector when calling `on`. Then on first part selector, use an element that doesn't change eg. document.

```
$(document).on("click","#selectyoursize_block_left a",function(e){});
```

Comment: hi aivan thanks for the reply.I have used that too.but nothing hapened.